# Swift - Cannot invoke '!' with an agrument of type UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

sorry my english is very bad :(

I have tried buil a application using UITavleView, but my application encounters an error as follows

[image: sceenshot]

help me fix this, Please :(

Thanks alot :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your code:

- `cell` is not an optional, so it can never be nil
- `cell` is downcasted to `Main_Customcell_1` using `as` - that causes a runtime exception if the cast is not possible, the optional downcast operator `as?` is safer
- `!cell` cannot be used to test for not nil, it's not allowed in swift - the correct way would be `cell != nil`

However, your fixed code should look like:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("main_customcell_1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? Main_CustomCell_1 {
    ...
}
```

Suggested reading: [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496)

Suggestion: textual code is preferred to screenshots - images are welcome if they provide additional details.